# #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, update, join

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос. Запрос должен полю users.cases присвоить количество записей для каждого юзера которые есть в таблице inventory по каждому из юзеров в диапазоне id юзеров 1 и 30

```
UPDATE users usr
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory inv 
    ON usr.id = inv.user
SET usr.cases = COUNT(inv.id)
WHERE usr.id BETWEEN 1 AND 300
```

не понимаю, в чем ошибка. #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: count не работает без group by (хотя бы неявного), а group by невозможен в update, так как делает одну запись из нескольких и исходных записей не остается. Напишите select запрос с group by, который посчитает количества в разрезе id пользователей. А затем этот запрос используйте в join update'а вместо таблицы inventory

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать следующий вариант запроса:

```
UPDATE users usr
LEFT JOIN (
    -- Суммируем количество записей по юзеру
    SELECT inv.user userid, COUNT(inv.id) AS cnt
    FROM inventory inv 
    WHERE inv.user BETWEEN 1 AND 300
    GROUP BY inv.user
) s ON usr.id = s.userid
-- Обновляем данные юзера
SET usr.cases = IFNULL(s.count, 0) -- Обнуляем NULL -> 0
WHERE usr.id BETWEEN 1 AND 300
```